# Configure network interfaces in Go

Tags: go

Does Go offer a way to configure network interfaces? I found a very easy to use [net.Interfaces](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interfaces) method to get the information, but i want to modify the network configuration.

Comment: I tried to rephrase some parts of your question and I hope I got it right. What do you want to modify? The IP address? Something else?

Comment: yea. i mean. manage the network adapter . bring up or down the iface, also add or remove IPADDRESS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to modify your network config, the best way would be to call external tools like `ip`, `iptables`, `ifconfig`, `brctl`, etc..
This is the way we do in within docker (https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/network.go#L72)

Comment: This answer is pretty much useless, he's asking about doing it in `Go` and your response is to use `ip`, `iptables`, `ifconfig`, `brctl`, `docker` !!!???

Comment: at the time (2013) this was the best answer for my problem, but now the library you suggest is better for the job, btw he wasnt suggesting me to use docker, he was saying that was the way docker internally used it

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using [netlink](https://github.com/vishvananda/netlink):

```golang
lnk, err := netlink.LinkByName("eth0")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

ipConfig := &netlink.Addr{IPNet: &net.IPNet{
    IP:   net.ParseIP("192.168.0.2"),
    Mask: net.CIDRMask(24, 32),
}}

if err = netlink.AddrAdd(lnk, ipConfig); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Please be warned that at the time of writing this library does not support other OS then Linux. So if you need a cross-platform solution then you will have to either use `ip`/`ipconfig`/`netsh` directly with `os/exec`, or look for some other libraries.